# Producing a correlation matrix with 3 decimal points

Tags: r, decimal, correlation

I am trying to produce a correlation matrix and i need the correlation coefficients to be at three decimals. I tried all I could find but I always end up with two decimals.

I tried following the advice from this post, but to no success. [How to force Hmisc package in R to round to 3 decimals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58495545/how-to-force-hmisc-package-in-r-to-round-to-3-decimals)

Is there a better package for spearmans correlation? Ive been at his for hours.

My other question is, is there a way to export the coefficients and give them some special signs if the correlation was significant? In my work, we display p<0,1 with a + after the coeficient, p<0,05 with a * (standard stuff).
This is what the coefficients look like:

```
       start januar   feb   mar   apr   maj   1-2   1-3   1-4   1-5   1-6   1-7   1-8   1-9  1-10  1-11
start   1.00  -0.33 -0.37 -0.64  0.23  0.11 -0.38 -0.57 -0.51 -0.40 -0.40 -0.40 -0.38 -0.42 -0.49 -0.60
januar -0.33   1.00  0.23  0.25  0.14  0.04  0.72  0.56  0.56  0.64  0.65  0.63  0.58  0.50  0.59  0.44
feb    -0.37   0.23  1.00  0.77 -0.08 -0.25  0.81  0.89  0.82  0.76  0.75  0.76  0.81  0.86  0.83  0.79
mar    -0.64   0.25  0.77  1.00  0.00 -0.24  0.66  0.86  0.85  0.75  0.73  0.76  0.78  0.81  0.75  0.79
apr     0.23   0.14 -0.08  0.00  1.00 -0.04  0.05 -0.03  0.21  0.27  0.27  0.22  0.13  0.16  0.13  0.12
```

Comment: This is usually a rendering thing, not a data thing. Set `options(digits=5)` and look at that object again to see if the number of digits shown changes.

Comment: Said differently, what R prints on the console is not necessarily the full story. Think of `pi`, where it might show only 3.14 but it is clearly much more precise than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't really tell what's not working for you from the linked question.

```
library(Hmisc)
cc <- Hmisc::rcorr(as.matrix(USArrests))
s <- format(round(cc$r, 3), digits = 3)
## add symbols
fstr <- function(x) {
  x[is.na(x)] <- 1
  symnum(x, cutpoints = c(0,0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1,1),
            symbols = c("***", "**", "*","+", " "))
}
s[] <- paste0(s, fstr(cc$P))
print(s, quote = FALSE)
```

```
         Murder   Assault  UrbanPop Rape    
Murder   1.000    0.802*** 0.070    0.564***
Assault  0.802*** 1.000    0.259+   0.665***
UrbanPop 0.070    0.259+   1.000    0.411** 
Rape     0.564*** 0.665*** 0.411**  1.000
```

(This is for Pearson correlations, but using `type = "spearman"` in the `rcorr()` call should get you what you want ...)

I've got coloured extensions working with the `crayon` package, but it's a significant PITA - `print()` and associated matrix formatting don't work, so (AFAIK) you more or less have to reinvent all that stuff (there may be an off-the-shelf way to do this but I don't know what it is ...)

```r
s <- format(round(cc$r, 3), digits = 3)
library(crayon)
s[] <- s %+% red(fstr(cc$P))
myprint <- function(s) {
    ## assume all numeric values are already formatted to the same length
    f <- matrix(NA_character_, nrow(s) + 1, ncol(s) + 2)
    tmpf <- function(a, b) {
        col_align(c(a, b), width = max(col_nchar(c(a,b))))
    }
    f[,1] <- tmpf("", rownames(s))
    for (i in 1:ncol(s)) {
        f[,i+1] <- tmpf(colnames(s)[i], s[,i])
    }
    f[,ncol(s) + 2] <- "\n"
    apply(f, 1, cat, sep = " ")
    invisible(s)
}
myprint(s)
```

Printing with `crayon` will be device-dependent (I can't show [coloured output in text on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115455/having-font-color-option-in-stack-overflow-question-editor)); it should work in RStudio, the R console, and most terminals/IDEs, but if you want to do something like print to a report (HTML or PDF) you may have to start over again ...

Comment: You probably were looking for `?symnum`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked, I had to adjust 
s <- substr(format(cc$r), 1, 5) to
s <- substr(format(cc$r), 1, 6), that got me to three decimals. 
Is there a way to incorporate printing the numbers with +.*.** etc. in red? I tried adding it, but to no luck, so Im probably doing it wrong. 
 fstr <- function(x) {
  ifelse(is.na(x) | x > 0.1, "",
         ifelse(x > 0.05, "+", 
                ifelse(x > 0.01, "*",
                       ifelse(x > 0.001, "**", "***",
                          ifelse(x > 0.1, color= "red")))))}

Comment: Also, this cuts off the rest of the digits. Is there a way to round the numbers, not just cut them?

Comment: Thank you. Since I need to export this to excel, and it turns into mishmash with thecrayon part, Ill stick to having it in black.